# Laravel simplify query method

Tags: php, laravel

In Book model I have 2 methods

1 for get book list another for get auth user Favourites book list. Two methods like below

For get book list :

```
public function getBooks($id = null)
{
    $query = $this::with("bookImages","author","category")->withCount(['favourites'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    return $id ? $query->findOrFail($id):$query;
}
```

For get user fav book list

```
public function getFavList()
{
        return $this::join('favorites', function($query){
                $query->on('books.id','=','favorites.book_id')->where('favorites.user_id', '=', 1);
            })
            ->with("bookImages","author","category")->withCount(['favourites'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ;
}
```

In both query `with` is common. So I'm trying to reuse getBooks method in getFavList method like below

```
public function getFavList()
{
        return $this::join('favorites', function($query){
                $query->on('books.id','=','favorites.book_id')->where('favorites.user_id', '=', 1);
            })
            ::$this->getBooks()
        ;
}
```

Here I'm getting `Access to undeclared static property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$this`. How can I simplify this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is :P

```
return $this->getBooks()->join('favorites',function($query){
    $query->on('books.id','=','favorites.book_id')->where('favorites.user_id', '=', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) under "Eager Loading"
Multiple relationships:

```
$books = Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();
```

Nested relationships:

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

So for you:

```
Advert::with('getBooks.getFavList')->find(1);
```

---

Another way -
You can even try the union method:

```
public function getFavBooks()
{
    return $this->getBooks()->union($this->getFavList()->toBase());
}
```

Comment: I don't this it's a Nested relationships issue. There case is find matching book list for auth user from favorites table. So why doI require nested ?

Comment: If used wisely this case is not much different than a nested relation.

Comment: With this question there has no any relation with nested ! question is how to reuse with method in 2nd method.

Comment: Ok, let me get back to you.

Comment: @NiloyRony Check the edited one